# Какие есть библиотеки для проверки подписок или лайков в соц сетях на react?

Tags: reactjs, telegram, api, youtube, facebook

Какие есть библиотеки для проверки подписок/лайков в соц сетях на react? (подписки / лайки на youtube, tg, facebook, twitter).
Нашел библиотеки, но там проверка подписок осуществляется через получение всех подписок с api tg бота и поиск в них соответствующего канала (это максимальный функционал, который я нашел :( ).